# Unable to access / var / tmp in Subprocess via Django

Tags: python, django

I created a script that outputs the execution result of a shell script to a Web screen using Django and subprocess of python.

Specifically, the following two scripts were created.

- test.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os
import subprocess
import syslog

command_list = ['/bin/sh', '/var/tmp/test.sh']

proc = subprocess.Popen(args=command_list,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    cwd=os.path.dirname(command_list[0]),
    shell=False)

result = proc.communicate(input=None)

print str( result )
```

- test.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "begin"
cat /var/tmp/data.txt
```

---

- data.txt

```
data1
data2
```

Unit tests were performed on the two scripts, and they were confirmed to work properly.

However, when I used test.py via Django, test.sh's "cat" command and data.txt existed,
“Cat: /var/tmp/data.txt: No such file or directory” is displayed.

What is the cause?

## version

- python 2.7.13
- Django 1.11.20

Comment: Please add the output of `id; ls -l /var/tmp` and details about your environment to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I set PrivateTmp to PrivateTmp = false, httpd can now access / var / tmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set PrivateTmp to PrivateTmp = false, httpd can now access / var / tmp.

```
view /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
    PrivateTmp=false

systemctl daemon-reload
service http restart
```